# vb.net, iterating through arraylists

Tags: vb.net

I have two arraylists that contains links in one and the root url in the other. Sometimes the lists dont equal in number and I would like to iterate through the links list and if it contains a matching root url add it to a third list but also avoid any duplicates. I tried this but am not getting consistent results.

Any ideas appreciated, thanks.

```
For Each link As String In urls
            For Each part As String In post
                If part.Contains(link) Then
                    newPost.Add(part)
                End If
            Next
       Next
```

Perhaps there is another way; basically the part in post is a link to a page and contains the root url( which is link in urls). After extracting all these I need to ensure the 2 lists match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 2008, then you can use LINQ

```
For each link as String in urls

    Dim results = (FROM part IN post _
                  SELECT part _
                  WHERE part.Contains(link)). Distinct
Next
```

You can replace the . Distinct by other functions like First, FirstOrDefault,ToList,ToArray,GroupBy,Sort, and the list goes on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it and it did not work. Let me add some more info for clarification.
Arraylist post contains the first few items as an example:
0 - http://www.blogdetecnologia.com/actualidad/aprobado-oficialmente-cargador-universal-microusb/
1- http://www.blogdetecnologia.com
2- http://landmine.com.ph/para-las-ventas-del-iphone-apple-original-3gs-32gb-en-200euros/
3- http://landmine.com.ph

and urls contains
0 - http://www.blogdetecnologia.com
1 - http://landmine.com.ph

this is what the problem is; i get new list with the same post items after iterating through it